# Makefiles and cross platform development

Tags: c, cross-platform, makefile

I have been trying to figure out how to create a C program that can be compiled for all of the major operating systems. I have considered using makefiles so I would just have to change the target OS, but I have a few problems. My first problem is that I cannot figure out how to change the target OS so I can compile on one OS but use the application on all OS's. My second issue is that I cannot figure out how to make it automatically compile all .c files in the src directory, so I do not have to modify the makefile every time I add a new file. Does anybody know how to do this stuff?

My current makefile (currently unmodified from [here](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/))

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@q2
```

Comment: Could you post an abbreviated makefile and abbreviated directory structure?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The directory structure would just be a directory with the makefile and a subdirectory called "src".

Comment: What operating system are you doing the compiling from?  What graphical toolkit (if any) are you using?  Are you using *any* libraries other than the C standard library?

Comment: I am planning to use only the standard C libraries and glew, but I am doing that on OS X and a simple text editor I made.

Comment: *"... I cannot figure out how to change the target OS so I can compile on one OS but use the application on all OS's"* I'm not sure that's possible with C - I don't think a binary compiled for OS X will be compatible with Windows\*.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner That is not at all what that means. I mean that I want to build _on_ OS X _for_ Windows. You seem to think I want some kind of a universal binary that all OS's can run.

Comment: @Justin: Ok, that wasn't clear in my initial reading of that. I really don't know if it's possible to build *on* OS X *for* Windows. It might be possible if your compiler *on* OS X knows how to build *for* Windows but I don't think I've ever seen anything like that (though it has been a while since I've done anything with C).

Comment: I agree with @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: I doubt that it's possible to compile on OSX for Windows. The second part is easy: `SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)`

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: it certainly is possible to compile for Windows on a Mac (with a little bit of effort) - it's called [cross-compiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).

Comment: Is there some parameter that I can change to make it compile for Windows? It does not even have to be in a makefile - I just need to be able to change it.

Comment: @Justin, no, it's not that simple. For example, even if you stick entirely to standard C libraries and dynamic linking you'd need to have Windows versions of the C standard header files and stub libraries. If you search google or stackoveflow for "windows cross compile" you'll get pointed to a bunch of articles about MinGW. This is probably the easiest package to get you set up for cross-compling for windows on a UNIX system, but it isn't simple. It may be easier to use a cross-platoform build system like CMake and just do the build on a Windows box.

Comment: @Mac, I stand corrected. I knew that it was possible *in principle*, but thought that it was so difficult as to be practically impossible; it appears that I was (probably) wrong.

Answer (score 6):

The GNU Autoconf is a good place to start.  I can't give you a complete answer because I don't know what you'd do for Windows except maintain a set of nmake scripts.  While there's a learning curve they make it possible to write make files and c-code that work across platforms.  It will not only handle multiple source files for you but help you define target such as 'all', 'install,' 'clean,' etc.  If you're familiar with downloading a project and then typing './configure' and then 'make install' then you've probably been a user of an Autoconf generated project.

There are other reasons to use Autoconf than just handling multiple source files.

What makes C/C++ development across flavors of Unix difficult is the definition of 'Unix' and C.  Different flavors of Unix have slightly different library or system calls depending on what flavor of standards they support.  The same is true of C.  So, when writing code you'll see #defines specifying a group of preprocessor symbols that define a version of Unix and C that you'd like to use.  Going from GCC to HP C or some other vendor's C compiler may include different 'default' levels of behavior, so you need to make the expected behavior explicit.

Second, you need to define what libraries are required.  In your build you might need to probe for mysql libraries and decide what to do if those libraries are not installed.  In some cases you might need to not build at all or in some cases you might just substitute for another library (like libdb).  Having tried writing complex makefiles to support even two operating systems (Solaris and Linux), I would not want to re-invent this wheel.