# A single makeFile-Windows/Linux/Mac OS

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

We have some applications written in C/C++ and makefiles for the same. Currently, we are using the GNU make system on windows (cygwin based). The makefiles were written long back considering only Windows OS in mind. Now we are going to revamp everything.

I am unaware of the factors to be considered while writing the makefiles so as to make them cross platform compatible. I looked at some Sources on the Internet, but they were unsatisfactory. Can someone please list out the issues to be considered while writing the makefiles so as to make them compatible across various platforms.

PS: I have seen this link, but i think it isn't what i want.
[Makefiles and cross platform development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234461/makefiles-and-cross-platform-development)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [cmake](http://cmake.org) - it's a cross platform tool which generates makefiles or projects files with respect to your platform. So instead of writing Makefile you write CMakeLists.txt, then you run cmake and it will generate Makefiles. When you want to compile your program on another platform you just ru-run cmake with different target project system.

Comment: If am bound not to use cmake, then?

Comment: Why are you bound not to use cmake?

Comment: A big reason not to use cmake is that cmake does not come included with macOS, or even with XCode command-line tools.  Hunting and installing this 3rd party tool adds an additional step, which may or may not be allowed by company security policy.